# In Stack, how do I find problematic constraint when "plan construction failed"?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I am not able to build with stack and would love to learn a strategy for resolving. Here is the current error:

```
In the dependencies for aeson-1.4.7.1:
    th-abstraction-0.4.3.0 from stack
                           configuration
                           does not
                           match >=0.2.8.0 && <0.4
                           (latest
                           matching
                           version
                           is 0.3.2.0)
needed due to app-0.0.2
               -> aeson-1.4.7.1
```

Edit: Resolver: lts-18.27

Notes and questions:

1. The package `aeson-1.4.7.1` is an extra-dep in my `stack.yaml` and it looks like it uses `th-abstraction-0.3.2.0`,see [link](https://www.stackage.org/lts-16.31/package/aeson-1.4.7.1/deps)
2. The `package.yaml` for the `app` I'm creating does not restrict versions
3. Given (1) and (2), there is some other constraint that leads to a requirement for `th-abstraction-0.4.3.0`. How can I find out where constraint is defined, presumably some other package? Because this is the package I need to change.

Comment: Which resolver / Stackage snapshot are you using?

Comment: Edited, thanks: lts-18.27

Comment: `th-abstraction-0.4.3.0` is the version included in [lts-18.27](https://www.stackage.org/lts-18.27). Try adding a compatible version of `th-abstraction` to your `extra-deps` or remove the incompatible `aeson-1.4.7.1` extra-dep.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you, this could've easily taken me days to figure out! It would be so nice if the error could say that: "th-abstraction-0.4.3.0 is a constraint introduced by your resolver lts-18.27", but maybe it's not possible to backwards infer this dependency. Also happy to accept this as an answer, maybe it's just the strategy to say "Always check what constraints LTS introduces"

Comment: Yeah. Sounds like a good feature request for `stack`.